# How do I map state into a component as a prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hey for some reason my questions aren't being rendered. I feel my issue may be with my QuizData.map but I can't tell what the issue is because I can console.log     console.log(quizData.map(item => item.question)) and get the results.

Any clue as to what may be causing this issue? Thank you!

**Parent Component**

```
export default function QuizData() {

const [quizData, setQuizData] = React.useState([{
    question: "",
    answers: "",
    correctAnswer: "",
    selectedAnswer: ""
}]);
React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5&category=12&difficulty=medium&type=multiple")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => setQuizData(data.results.map(item => ({
            question: item.question,
            answers: item.incorrect_answers.concat(item.correct_answer),
            correctAnswer: item.correct_answer
        }))))
},[]) 
return (
    <div>
        
        {quizData.map((item) => {
            <div>
                <Question 
                    question={item.question}
                    answers={item.answer}
                    chosenAnswer={quizData.selectedAnswer}
                    updateAnswers={handleSelectedAnswer}
                />
            </div>
        })}
          <button
            onClick={() => {
                    checkSelectedAnswer();
                    scoreQuiz();
                    finishQuiz()
                    }
                }>
            Check answers
        </button>
  </div>
)}
```

**Child component**

```
export default function Question(props) {

return (
    <div>
                
                    {props.question.map(item => <h3>item</h3>)}
                    
                    {props.answers.map((item, index) => {
                        <div key={index}>
                            <input
                                type="radio"
                                name={`answer option-${item}`}
                                id={`answer-options-${index}`}
                                value={props.chosenAnswer}
                                onChange={props.updateAnswers}
                            />
                            <label htmlFor={`answer-options-${index}`}>{answerOption}</label>
                        </div>
                    })}
                   
    </div>
)}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should return the mapped element, as:

```
return (
    <div>     
        {quizData.map((item) => {
           return <div>
                <Question 
                    question={item.question}
                    answers={item.answer}
                    chosenAnswer={quizData.selectedAnswer}
                    updateAnswers={handleSelectedAnswer}
                />
            </div>
        })}
  </div>
)
```

or

```
    return (
      <div>     
          {quizData.map((item) => (<div>
                     <Question 
                      question={item.question}
                      answers={item.answer}
                      chosenAnswer={quizData.selectedAnswer}
                      updateAnswers={handleSelectedAnswer}
                  />
              </div>
    ))}
    </div>
  )
```

Update it in both the maps

Comment: `quizData.selectedAnswer`? Are you sure?

Comment: Thanks Andy I changed it to item.selectedAnswer.

@NeERAJ seems the only difference is that you're adding a return before the first <div> in map right? If so I'm getting an error with that. 

I'm not closing the first <div> inside the original return because I'm assuming I need it for <button>

Comment: @agm can you update the question with complete code? or create a sandbox?

Comment: Does this work? https://scrimba.com/scrim/co6a240dfa1cc064e4dffd2f6

Comment: @agm yes. thanks

Comment: Note: [you can create React snippets in SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002). Very useful for testing your answers.